# Error in passing parameters to stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, stored-procedures, odbc

I have created a stored procedure for inserting values in a table. This is the stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[insertproc]
    @CollectionPersonName varchar(50), 
    @Address varchar(1500),
    @ContactNo varchar(50),
    @CreatedBy int,
    @CreatedOn datetime
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    insert into CollectionPersonDetails(CollectionPersonName, Address, ContactNo, CreatedBy, CreatedOn)   
    values(@CollectionPersonName, @Address, @ContactNo, @CreatedBy, @CreatedOn);
END
```

Below is the function that I have written for passing parameters and executing the query in the stored procedure:

```
public static int SaveDataProcedure(tblCollectionPersonObj oSaveObj, int iUserId)
{
        string query = "insertproc";

        OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection(Connect.ConnectionString());

        OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("insertproc",conn);
        cmd.CommandText = query;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;            

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CollectionPersonName",   oSaveObj.SCollectionPersonName);            
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", oSaveObj.SAddress);           
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContactNo", oSaveObj.SPhoneNo);            
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CreatedBy", iUserId);          
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CreatedOn", CommonData.GetDateForDatabase(DateTime.Now));            

        cmd.Connection.Open();

        int i= cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        cmd.Connection.Close();
        return i;
    }
```

I am getting an error which says stored procedure expects the parameter `@collectionPersonName` which was not supplied. I have tried using `parameters.add` function as well, but the same error was shown.

I can see the values coming when I debug through the code but when the execution comes to `ExecuteNonQuery()` that's the point where I get the error.The mistake might be very silly but I haven't been able to find it.

Kindly help.

Comment: What is the value of `oSaveObj.SCollectionPersonName` when you debug it?

Comment: @SonerGönül , the value of oSaveObj.SCollectionPersonName is coming as expected.There is no problem with that.

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: @TVicky, is there a reason for you to use `OdbcConnection`, not `SqlConnection`? Your code looks correct, maybe it is some issue with connection?

Comment: Yes @AndyKorneyev ,to try out what you said,I just replaced OdbcConnection with SqlConnection in my code and it worked.But I am sure there has to be a way to get this working with Odbc as well.

Answer (score 0):

`AddWithValue` method will not add parameter, if value is null.

Check if `oSaveObj.SCollectionPersonName` is null and use `DBNull.Value` in this case

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CollectionPersonName",   oSaveObj.SCollectionPersonNamу ?? DBNull.Value);
```

Comment: I have debugged that part of the code and I found that oSaveObj.SCollectionPersonName had a value,it was not null.